# Windows Azure Server 2019 RDP "The connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote login"

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have two Azure servers. Server 1 is the Active Directory / RDP licensing server. Server 2 is the one my users will access.

Up to a couple of weeks ago, prior to doing AD, I had local accounts on the server and everything worked fine. Now with AD, it is not.

I have an admin account and a user account. When I try to RDP into Server 2 with the user account, I get the error "The connection was denied because the user account is not authorized for remote login." This account is part of the Remote Desktop users group.

I have tried making changes to local policies on both servers, etc., to no available. When I try to add users in Remote Desktop settings on Server 2, when I click the link, nothing happens. I assume this is because of using AD.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I learned something new. Here's the answer in case anyone else runs into it.

When I was trying to RDP into the server, I was using an RDP file that I downloaded from the Azure console. When using that RDP to log into the server, I would get this error. When I RDP'd into the server directly using an IP address, I could access the server.

The problem is using the RDP file with a non-admin account. Open the RDP file in notepad and you will see the line: administrative session:i:1. If the non-admin account does not have admin rights, you will not be able to log into the server because of this line. If I set this flag's value to 0 (administrative session:i:0), I can use the RDP file with a non-admin account.

I did not know that there was an admin flag like this in a RDP file.